# text.replace(punctuation,'') does not remove all punctuation contained in list(punctuation)?

Tags: python, string, list, replace, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib2,sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
from string import punctuation as p

# URL for Obama's presidential acceptance speech in 2008
obama_4427_url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427'

# read in URL
obama_4427_html = urllib2.urlopen(obama_4427_url).read()

# BS magic
obama_4427_soup = BeautifulSoup(obama_4427_html)

# find the speech itself within the HTML
obama_4427_div = obama_4427_soup.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})

# obama_4427_div.text.lower() removes extraneous characters (e.g. '<br/>')
# and places all letters in lowercase
obama_4427_str = obama_4427_div.text.lower()

# for further text analysis, remove punctuation
for punct in list(p):
    obama_4427_str_processed = obama_4427_str.replace(p,'')
obama_4427_str_processed_2 = obama_4427_str_processed.replace(p,'')
print(obama_4427_str_processed_2)

# store individual words
words = obama_4427_str_processed.split(' ')
print(words)
```

Long story short, I have a speech from President Obama, and am looking to remove all punctuation, so that I'm left only with the words. I've imported the `punctuation` module, ran a `for` loop which didn't remove all my punctuation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No, `str.replace()` replaces *literal text only*.

Comment: `for punct in list(p):` you are never using `punct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replace()` searches for the *whole value of the first argument*. It is not a pattern, so only if the *whole* `string.punctuation* value is there will this be replaced with an empty string.

Use a regular expression instead:

```
import re
from string import punctuation as p

punctuation = re.compile('[{}]+'.format(re.escape(p)))

obama_4427_str_processed = punctuation.sub('', obama_4427_str)
words = obama_4427_str_processed.split()
```

Note that you can just use `str.split()` without an argument to split on any arbitrary-width whitespace, including newlines.

Comment: When I `print(obama_4427_str_processed`, I get no read-out. I just get the `print(obama_4427_str_processed` command spit back out at me. How can I make it print the entire body of text?

Comment: @GBR24: my apologies, I had the arguments for `regexpattern.sub()` mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the punctuation you can `rstrip` it off:

```
obama_4427_str = obama_4427_div.text.lower()

# for further text analysis, remove punctuation
from string import punctuation
print([w.rstrip(punctuation) for w in obama_4427_str.split()])
```

Output:

```
['transcript', 'to', 'chairman', 'dean', 'and', 'my', 'great', 
'friend', 'dick', 'durbin', 'and', 'to', 'all', 'my', 'fellow', 
'citizens', 'of', 'this', 'great', 'nation', 'with', 'profound', 
'gratitude', 'and', 'great', 'humility', 'i', 'accept', 'your', 
'nomination', 'for', 'the', 'presidency', 'of', 'the', 'united',
................................................................
```

using python3 to remove from anywhere use str.translate:

```
from string import punctuation
tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):"" for ch in punctuation})
obama_4427_str = obama_4427_div.text.lower().translate(tbl)
print(obama_4427_str.split())
```

For python2:

```
from string import punctuation
obama_4427_str = obama_4427_div.text.lower().encode("utf-8").translate(None,punctuation)
print( obama_4427_str.split())
```

Output:

```
['transcript', 'to', 'chairman', 'dean', 'and', 'my', 'great', 
'friend', 'dick', 'durbin', 'and', 'to', 'all', 'my', 'fellow', 
'citizens', 'of', 'this', 'great', 'nation', 'with', 'profound', 
'gratitude', 'and', 'great', 'humility', 'i', 'accept', 'your', 
'nomination', 'for', 'the', 'presidency', 'of', 'the', 'united',
............................................................
```

On a another note, you can iterate over a string so `list(p)` is redundant in your own code.

Comment: I'm using Python2.7 :(

Comment: @GBR24, you can use the first code in python2, are you actually trying to replace anywhere or just strip it off? You can also use translate with python2 using encode